# elasticsearch spend all time in build_scorer

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

When we've upgraded our ES from ES 1.4 to ES 5.2 we got performance problem with such type of queries:

```
{
  "_source": false,
  "from": 0,
  "size": 50,
  "profile": true,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "ids": {
            "values": [<list of 400 ids>],
            "boost": 1
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "views": [ <list od 20 ints> ]
    }
      ]
      "minimum_should_match": "0",
      "boost": 1
    }
  }
}
```

When profiling we found that the problem with build_scorer, which call for each segment:

1 shard;

20 segments;

took: 55

```
{
    "type": "BooleanQuery",
    "description": "views:[9875227 TO 9875227] views:[6991599 TO 6991599] views:[6682953 TO 6682953] views:[6568587 TO 6568587] views:[10080097 TO 10080097] views:[9200174 TO 9200174] views:[9200174 TO 9200174] views:[10080097 TO 10080097] views:[9966870 TO 9966870] views:[6568587 TO 6568587] views:[6568587 TO 6568587] views:[8538669 TO 8538669] views:[8835038 TO 8835038] views:[9200174 TO 9200174] views:[7539089 TO 7539089] views:[6991599 TO 6991599] views:[8222303 TO 8222303] views:[9342166 TO 9342166] views:[7828288 TO 7828288] views:[9699294 TO 9699294] views:[9108691 TO 9108691] views:[9431297 TO 9431297] views:[7539089 TO 7539089] views:[6032694 TO 6032694] views:[9491741 TO 9491741] views:[9498225 TO 9498225] views:[8051047 TO 8051047] views:[9866955 TO 9866955] views:[8222303 TO 8222303] views:[9622214 TO 9622214]",
    "time": "39.70427700ms",
    "breakdown": {
        "score": 99757,
        "build_scorer_count": 20,
        "match_count": 0,
        "create_weight": 37150,
        "next_doc": 0,
        "match": 0,
        "create_weight_count": 1,
        "next_doc_count": 0,
        "score_count": 110,
        "build_scorer": 38648674,
        "advance": 918274,
        "advance_count": 291
    },
```

So 38 ms of total 55ms was taken by build_scorer, it seems weired.

On ES 1.5 we have about the same number of segments but query run 10x faster
Unfortunately ES 1.x doesn't have profiler to check how many times build_scorer executes in ES 1.x

So the question is why build_scorer_count equal to number of segments and how can we tackle this performance issue?

Comment: The workaround we've found is just:


1. recreate index regularly
2. merge segments
3. switch alias on new index


This apporach helps to avoid bloating number of segments